# Not being able to scroll, as required, via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a bit of a problem involving scrolling in jQuery.
I am designing a portfolio page that tends to have 3 sections - 'about-section', 'portfolio-section' & 'contact-section'.
I am wanting to add a class to the navbar-links of the different sections of the page, when the page scrolls to that very section.
The problem arises whilst I try to scroll to the 'contact-section' as when I try to do so, the class is added to the 'contact' navbar-link in the navbar way before I reach the contact section.

My code is as follows ..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(".navbar-links").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-links").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
  
  var about_offset = $("#about-section").offset().top;
  
  var portfolio_offset = $("#portfolio-section").offset().top;
  
  var contact_offset = $("#contact-section").offset().top;
  
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".navbar-links").removeClass("active");
    var scrolled_offset = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrolled_offset>=contact_offset)
      {
        $("#contact_link").addClass("active");
      }
    else if(scrolled_offset>=portfolio_offset)
      {
        $("#portfolio_link").addClass("active");
      }
    else
      {
        $("#about_link").addClass("active");
      }
  });
  
  $("button").click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("navbar-toggle"))
      window.open($(this).val(),"_blank"); 
  });
                             
  $("#proj_img_1").click(function(){
    window.open("https://codepen.io/iamrkcheers/full/JKbqjw/","_blank");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color : black;
}

.heading {
  font-family : Sofia;
}

button {
  background : transparent;
  border : 1px solid white;
  padding : 0px;
  margin : 10px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size : 27px;
}

#navbar-menu {
  text-align : center;
}

.navbar-links {
  font-size : 20px;
}

.active {
  border : 1px solid white;
}

a {
  color : green;
}

#about-section {
  background-color : #fd746c;
  color : black;
  z-index : 1;
  position : relative;
  box-shadow : 10px 10px 20px black;
}

.center {
  text-align : center;
}

.content-div {
  text-align : center;
  display : inline-block;
  vertical-align : middle;
  float : none;
}

.content {
  font-family : Lily Script One;
}

i {
  border : 0px;
}

img {
  border : 1px solid black;
  margin : auto;
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
  right : 0;
  bottom : 0;
  box-shadow : 10px 10px 20px black;
}

.project-img {
  max-width : 70%;
  max-height : 70%;
}

#portfolio-section {
  background-color : #904e95;
  color : black;
  position : relative;
  box-shadow : 10px 10px 20px black;
}

#proj_img_div{
  position : relative;
}

#proj_img_1:hover + #img_desc {
  visibility : visible;
  opacity : 1;
}

#proj_img_1:hover {
    opacity : 0.4;
}

#img_desc {
  position : absolute;
  top : 50%;
  left : 0;
  width : 100%;
  text-align : center;
  color : black;
  visibility : hidden;
  opacity : 0;
  transition : opacity .5s, visibility .5s;
}

#contact-section {
  background-color : #4ca1af;
  color : black;
}

.fa {
  padding : 20px;
  font-size : 45px;
  width : 100px;
  text-align : center;
  text-decoration : none;
  background : #2c4762;
  color: white;
  margin : 0px 0px;
  border : 1px solid white;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity : 0.7;
}

#meta-section {
  background-color : #4ca1af;
  color : black;
  text-align : center;
}

hr {
  border-color : black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="navbar-section">
      <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
        <div class="navbar-header heading">
          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Portfolio Page</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right heading">
            <li class="navbar-links active" id="about_link"><a href="#about-section">About</a><li>
            <li class="navbar-links" id="portfolio_link"><a href="#portfolio-section">Portfolio</a><li>
            <li class="navbar-links" id="contact_link"><a href="#contact-section">Contact</a><li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid" id="scrollable-div">
  <div class="row" id="about-section">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="center heading">
      <h1>About</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 content-div content">
          <h3>Rishabh Kashyap</h3>
          <h3>Full Stack Web Developer</h3>
          <h3>Key Interests - JavaScript & MEAN Stack</h3>
          <h3>Worked as an intern @ Sapient Global Markets</h3>
          <h4><i>"Never be afraid to take risks. If you succeed, you can lead and if you fail, you can guide."</i><h4>
          <h4>- Swami Vivekananda</h4>
          <h3>Indeed. The motto, I try to live by. Professionally, as well as, Personally.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 content-div">
          <img class="img-responsive project-img" alt="my image" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/34CJNU0DexpintEhsM5-zcZdT_7mRWVA6dE-7f122WM3xj4xFI0nXYQhXyEG8tyrd4piHPHPGtCNtu_o5vqZ2eFFH2W9YS4ekKCqw7wgZzAjsKD8hdNoV5DrARz7I-BRljjksmdfHxoHaGIgwxcNYRJkEBa2FLIhbluVGZo1qN3zZ1ZJ1WpRU27mBbrCScNzazuOFtY0lOBX4JAKd7yGlC7ILwg4gAy-KsN-ZJz54PoNeCblgrz3jGsF8YvEf5Hc-V3kV8DtrDiKiwTpXPowvrLdldS-rIlOpjq1LrbPVNxWUNB1YieiqOUo1AEVYaS9WxiIFae2etL7Jb4nAW9MkLHE-YvQZ4VVcntRfXS3CBnuoy6EPHu2vfevnNeK9lgANs4rb1MNyMCxOACWmn45_vZKZoPfnmk_cyVzt7m2vFZUXPMdyeSRrViQD9VteriL89XHZlItrlgIhXI1vt5JAASHdOYrNV3CTpWMGPfzQk0BfQbbr2qcxnbgbSyEmK4M1wIloFQ0O_q-MCOdffySKCmct8iHRRrAcG5cWF_ArcX5GptL3tHAQHu9UCyfrjwIyI28NbrgZM0NkxxmpRAV5nRJGQetgxewxGaS2A6xfWnlW8jP-P4z=w479-h638-no?.jpg"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="portfolio-section">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="center heading">
      <h1>Portfolio</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="proj_img_div" class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
      <img id="proj_img_1" class="img-responsive project-img" alt="portfolio page" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/A2SpPv6o-FoZiuunHOW-bedHiyRRX3uQmhTgS9hIEgNeTorRJuycZWVdB0IZkIv80omce-6wP9TvbSYP1BStXBMk_scwves3_rQT14Q6oDJy-S0PlcmEESpDOTJEIBsmi3pihU2J9ZiO6VgzvUq5Be7x1I7XZPMmZwdFN0EMC2B8NDpfFO92m5qSRsIk50seJ_HBf1ear85c8l-ON-MbecU4Slkt67THjHIeZAGSigVmu7lUBrqf7fST-h-vF90RlSKhOVmK73vqr36I98XEVN9opd5HUYOIGbdlNmYhpFS5Ltjex1UY4tP7drLoZPy5zWG0cK1rpUuh7DhLV6o2rj1gTj2smARIIfqjlnf5KWfQNmZYCyPf4Prq2TKc0ijZ-yoyBrfd2dQb295JSaS08v1glC-rbhdsHNHVqIf7fjEC_6iH2k9Co3KG4Kt2CZIWQvZWW9Tz8zBPDbO1rpP0E4O9nmux4_PCW1S0G0AfC6aBpPshGvLLbP1zqAomzBxViRdGZQMh-eSMAVk7cS6GV5TFlqcKOsqHUPa5c58O-Sbzg-WfyczOPyy3ngDGatP5j4bYdZalaVuC06vXHAyqo2w39tGOqQjTa2ABgCWkljuh_Si4=w398-h223-no?.jpg">
      <div id="img_desc"><p><i>A tribute page to Swami Vivekananda using basic HTML & Bootstrap.</i></p></div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="contact-section" style="border : 5px solid red">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="center heading">
      <h1>Contact Me</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
      <div class="center">
        <h4><i>rishabhkashyap.rk@gmail.com</i></h4>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="center">
        <button value="https://www.facebook.com/rishabh.kashyap.940436"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></button><br>
        <button value="https://twitter.com/iamrkcheers"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></button>
        <button value="https://github.com/iamrkcheers"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></button>
        <button value="https://www.freecodecamp.com/iamrkcheers"><i class="fa fa-free-code-camp"></i></button><br>
        <button value="https://www.linkedin.com/in/rishabh-kashyap-735879117/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="meta-section">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
      <hr>
      <h5>Written & Coded by</h5>
      <h5><a href="https://github.com/iamrkcheers" target="_blank">Rishabh kashyap</a><h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The link for my code is ..

https://codepen.io/iamrkcheers/pen/KmxEpw

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the `about-offset` variable, `portfolio-offset` variable & `contact-offset` variable inside the `$(window).scroll()` function did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to be something like this?

https://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/awmyoQ?editors=1000

the only thing that is missing is some more space in the footer,, the page needs to be longer let's say

```
<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully following script will prevent your problem.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".navbar-links").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-links").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

    var aChildren = $("nav li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
    var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
    for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
        var aChild = aChildren[i];
        var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
        aArray.push(ahref);
    } // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values
    $(window).scroll(function(){
            var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
            var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
            var docHeight = $(document).height();

            for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
                var theID = aArray[i];
                var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
                var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
                if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                    $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("active");
                } else {
                    $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("active");
                }
            }

            if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
                if (!$("nav li:last-child a").hasClass("active")) {
                    var navActiveCurrent = $(".active").attr("href");
                    $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("active");
                    $("nav li:last-child a").addClass("active");
                }
            }
        });

  $("button").click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("navbar-toggle"))
      window.open($(this).val(),"_blank"); 
  });

  $("#proj_img_1").click(function(){
    window.open("https://codepen.io/iamrkcheers/full/JKbqjw/","_blank");
  });

});
</script>
```

> And one thing you need to do is remove `active` class from About nav link

If you need further info then you can look [here](http://callmenick.com/post/single-page-site-with-smooth-scrolling-highlighted-link-and-fixed-navigation)